# Method of undetermined coefficients can fail?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

We had the following differential equation:

$y^{''''} - 16y = e^{-2x}$

The homogeneous solution we get does not involve the $e^{-2x}$ term and hence that was our first guess for the particular solution but this fails to yield a particular solution that satisfies the equation. We get  0 = $e^{-2x}$. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Try $$y_p = a x e^{-2x}$$ Also, I'd review this page to see what to do in situations like this: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/undeterminedcoefficients.aspx

Comment: Can you tell me why it intuitively makes sense for you to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But the homogeneous solution does involve $e^{-2x}$. You have

$$y_h(x)=a e^{2x} + b e^{-2x} + c \cos(2x) + d \sin(2x),$$

and, therefore, you should try $y_p(x) = k x e^{-2x}$.

Comment: Oh, I must have made a mistake when solving for the homogenous equation.